# "error: use of deleted function"

Tags: c++

Estou com problema ao compilar o exemplo abaixo, plataforma linux para o esp8266, preciso de exemplo de como retornar um objeto através de uma função de classe para outra classe. Como exemplo: preciso ter acesso ao objeto (c) definido na classe C, na classe A.

```
 #include "b.h"
    #include "c.h"
    class A
    {
        public:
           int start();
        private:            
            B b;
            C c;
            int x;      


    }

    a.cpp

    int A::start()
    {
        c = b.copy();
        x = c.d;
        return x;
    }



    #include "c.h"
    class B
    {
        private:
            C c;        
        public:
            C copy();
    }

    b.cpp

    C B::copy()
    {
        c.add(1);   
        return c;
    }


    class C
    {           
        public:
            void add(int x);
            int d;
    }

    c.cpp

    void c.add(int x)
    {
        C::d = x + 10;
        return;
    }


    main()
   {   
      A a;
      int y;

      y = a.start();

      cout << y ;

   }
```

Ao tentar compilar em Linux o exemplo acima o mesmo apresenta o erro : ***"error: use of deleted function"***.

Comment: Fechei como não pode ser reproduzido porque esse problema não ocorre nesse código, ocorre outro. Vou repetir o que já falei anteriormente, veja [ask] e também faça um [mcve]. Note que o ideal seria ter colocado o *header*. Talvez ele cause o problema relatado, mas na forma como o `.cpp` foi escrito não parece que precise existir o *header*, talvez cause até prolema de redundância. Pra gente ajudar precisamos de uma pergunta com informações relevantes, precisamos conseguir ver o problema que está relatando. Eu reabro se a pergunta melhorar.

Comment: Ok Obrigado, porém o assunto é bem mais complexo, terei que instanciar as classes através de ponteiro, para que eu possa acessar esta, mesmo estando em uma classe diferente e não referenciada ou extendida.